# Meteor - Using FS returns TypeError: Cannot read property 'Collection' of undefined

Tags: angularjs, node.js, angular-meteor

I am using Meteor 1.6 and AngularJS (Angular 1) and am having issues in my /server/main.js file. I am trying to do an import like this:

```
import { FS } from 'meteor/cfs:filesystem';
```

So Meteor is able to resolve it just fine, but the problem is, it is undefined somehow. So when I do this:

```
Images = new FS.Collection("images", {
```

I get the error mentioned above. I have been trying to find answers online and I've been referencing the [Meteor Collection FS Documentation](https://github.com/CollectionFS/Meteor-CollectionFS) but haven't been able to resolve what I'm doing wrong with my import. Can anyone direct me how to fix this?

Comment: Please try this `import  FS  from 'meteor/cfs:filesystem';` instead of `import { FS } from 'meteor/cfs:filesystem';`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed out on a Meteor forum, the trick with this one it to NOT import it. I don't know why I didn't try that before, but apparently the `meteor/cfs:filesystem` doesn't use `api.export` in their `package.js` file, so you can't import it. I was brought up to speed by robfallows in the [Meteor forum](https://forums.meteor.com/t/meteor-using-fs-returns-typeerror-cannot-read-property-collection-of-undefined/41455)

Answer (score 0):

Please try this import * as FS from 'meteor/cfs:filesystem'; instead of import { FS } from 'meteor/cfs:filesystem'

Answer (score 0):

It should be as follows,

```
import { FS } from 'meteor/cfs:base-package';
import { FileSystem } from 'meteor/skaro:filesystem';
```